# optimize MSE algorithm using openmp

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, openmp, mse

I wanted to optimize below code using openMP

```
double val;
double m_y = 0.0f;
double m_u = 0.0f;
double m_v = 0.0f;

#define _MSE(m, t) \
val = refData[t] - calData[t];  \
m += val*val; 

#pragma omp parallel 
 {
 #pragma omp for
for( i=0; i<(width*height)/2; i++ ) {  //yuv422: 2 pixels at a time
    _MSE(m_u, 0); 
    _MSE(m_y, 1); 
    _MSE(m_v, 2); 
    _MSE(m_y, 3); 

  #pragma omp reduction(+:refData) reduction(+:calData)
    refData += 4;
    calData += 4;
 // int id = omp_get_thread_num();
 //printf("Thread %d performed %d iterations of the loop\n",id ,i);
}

}
```

Any suggestion welcome for optimizing above code currently I have wrong output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest thing you can do is allow it to split into 4 threads, and calculate the UYVY errors in each of those.  Instead of making them separate values, make them an array:

```
double sqError[4] = {0};
const int numBytes = width * height * 2;

#pragma omp parallel for
for( int elem = 0; elem < 4; elem++ ) {
    for( int i = elem; i < numBytes; i += 4 ) {
        int val = refData[i] - calData[i];
        sqError[elem] += (double)(val*val);
    }
}
```

This way, each thread operates exclusively on one thing and there is no contention.

Maybe it's not the most advanced use of OMP, but you should see a speedup.

---

After your comment about performance hit, I did some experiments and found that indeed the performance was worse.  I suspect this may be due to cache misses.

You said:

> performance hit this time with openMP : Time :0.040637 with serial
>   Time :0.018670

So I reworked it using the reduction on each variable and using a single loop:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:e0) reduction(+:e1) reduction(+:e2) reduction(+:e3)
    for( int i = 0; i < numBytes; i += 4 ) {
        int val = refData[i] - calData[i];
        e0 += (double)(val*val);
        val = refData[i+1] - calData[i+1];
        e1 += (double)(val*val);
        val = refData[i+2] - calData[i+2];
        e2 += (double)(val*val);
        val = refData[i+3] - calData[i+3];
        e3 += (double)(val*val);
    }
```

With my test case on a 4-core machine, I observed a little less than 4-fold improvement:

```
serial:             2025 ms
omp with 2 loops:   6850 ms
omp with reduction: 455  ms
```

---

**[Edit]** On the subject of why the first piece of code performed worse than the non-parallel version, *Hristo Iliev* said:

> Your first piece of code is a terrible example of what false sharing
>   does in multithreaded codes. As sqError has only 4 elements of 8 bytes
>   each, it fits in a single cache line (even in a half cache line on
>   modern x86 CPUs). With 4 threads constantly writing to neighbouring
>   elements, this would generate a massive amount of inter-core cache
>   invalidation due to false sharing. One can get around this by using
>   instead a structure like this struct _error { double val; double
>   pad[7]; } sqError[4]; Now each sqError[i].val will be in a separate
>   cache line, hence no false sharing.

Comment: Thank you paddy, I quickly make these changes and tested , this removes the data dependency and Improve the performance as well . however the calculated parallel openmp output is not same as the serial program output.

Comment: Are you saying that if you comment out the `#pragma` line, the results are different?  Or are you comparing it with a different program?  Since this is C, you might be defining `i` outside the loop.  If that's the case, try adding the clause `private(i)` to the end of your `#pragma` line.  Same with `val`.

Comment: For reference these are the changes I made : 

const int nBytes =  (width*height)/2;
    double sqError[4] = {0};     
  
  
 
#pragma omp parallel 
{
  #pragma omp for
   for(int elem = 0 ; elem <4 ; elem++) {
      for(int i = elem; i < nBytes; i+=4) {
          double val = refData[i] - calData[i];
          sqError[elem] += (double)(val*val);
      }
   }
}

    mse_y = ((double)(sqError[1] + sqError[3] )/ ( width * height ));
    mse_u = ((double)sqError[0] / ( width * height / 2 ));
    mse_v = ((double)sqError[2] / ( width * height / 2 ));

Comment: Right, so you misread my answer.  `nBytes` is NOT `(width*height)/2`.  Notice that I am incrementing `i` in steps of 4.

Comment: okay output with new modification has same output as serial version, however it is not same as what I had with previous version I posted.

Comment: You'll have to decide which is correct.  Your original, if parallel, would have some serious problems updating the values of `m_u`, `m_v` and `m_y`, especially with their dependence on the temporary `val`.  Oh, I also notice that you do not initialise them to zero.  Think what happens when that loop runs in parallel.  At the very least, remove the OMP stuff from your original.  If in doubt, fabricate two small test cases where you know what the result will be.

Comment: oh yeah, I got it same :) however performance hit this time with openMP : Time :0.040637 with serial Time :0.018670

Comment: Yeah I have been doing same to avoid confusion . in original code I have initialize them to zero as well . As this version consuming more time I would look for some other way to optimizes it. Thank you for assistance and please keep assisting :)

Comment: I have edited my answer after doing some experiments.  Please see the new section at the bottom.  Hope that helps.

Comment: that's great workaround, with openMP (reduction) Time :0.002887 and serial Time :0.018670 more than 6 fold. Thank you so much @paddy big applaud for you :)

Comment: You must have a nice processor =)  Glad to help.  Thanks to you too.  I haven't done much OMP and hadn't seen the `reduction` clause before.  You were using it incorrectly, but the fact you had it there made me go and do some reading.  Another tool for the belt!

Comment: yes I have 8 core(i-7) that makes the difference and I am learning while doing just a beginner to OMP. 

once again thank you for the input :)

Comment: Your first piece of code is a terrible example of what false sharing does in multithreaded codes. As `sqError` has only 4 elements of 8 bytes each, it fits in a single cache line (even in a half cache line on modern x86 CPUs). With 4 threads constantly writing to neighbouring elements, this would generate a massive amount of inter-core cache invalidation due to false sharing. One can get around this by using instead a structure like this `struct _error { double val; double pad[7]; } sqError[4];` Now each `sqError[i].val` will be in a separate cache line, hence no false sharing.

Comment: Thank you Hristo for valuable input, I tried that as well and have them optimized for more than 6 fold too :)

Comment: @HristoIliev You mean a "great example", right?  I didn't know the details of why this performed so badly.  Excellent comment, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like it's calculating the MSE but adding to the same sum, `m`. For parallelism to work properly, you need to eliminate sharing of `m`, one approach would be preallocating an array (width*height/2 I imagine) just to store the different sums, or `m`s. Finally, add up all the sums at the end.

Also, test that this is actually faster!

Comment: Thank you Cong for input we have tried with however it hit the performance . looking for some other version.